# Conformal mapping circle onto square (and back)

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, conformal-geometry, cartography

I'm programming an implementation of the Peirce quincuncial map projection. The projection involves a stereographic projection of a hemisphere of the globe onto a circle (I've got that part), then mapping points on that circle onto a square with a conformal mapping.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peirce_quincuncial_projection#Formal_description) describes the relationship between a point $(p, \theta)$ on the circle and a point $(x, y)$ on the square as

$$\tan \left( \frac{p}{2} \right) e^{i \theta} = \mathrm{cn} \left( z, \frac{1}{2} \right), \text{ where } z = x + i y.$$

I don't understand the notation $\mathrm{cn} \left( z, \frac{1}{2} \right)$. Can it be written using algebraic and trigonometric functions?

That is, can you rewrite the above like this?

$\tan \left( \frac{p}{2} \right) \cos\theta = $ something in terms of $x$ and $y$

$\tan \left( \frac{p}{2} \right) \sin\theta = $ something in terms of $x$ and $y$

Thanks.

Comment: since 'w'is hanging , maybe it's mis-transcribed 'w'? Still doesn't make sense to me. You can use complex log/exp - but your circle will be an annulus.

Comment: @greggo $w$ is not hanging. $z$ and $w$ are point and image point, and $w$ enters on the left of the equation (using its polar components $p$ and $\theta$), wheras $z$ enters on the right is inside a [Jacobi elliptic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions) - not that this would facilitate things (else we might expect a simler formula in Wikipedia)

Comment: (looks up pierce...) ok, weirder than I thought. The transform appears to reach singularities (infinite scale) at the square corners, allowing those corners to map to points at the boundary of the circle while still being conformal. Cool...

Comment: Sorry, the w is just a distraction. It's a relic of my copy and paste from Wikipedia. I removed it and also tried to clarify what I'm looking for in an answer.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz%E2%80%93Christoffel_mapping#Square there appear to be plenty of materials on numerical implementation of these

Comment: I published a Python package that implements some mappings: [`pip install squircle`](https://pypi.org/project/squircle/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\mathrm{cn}$ function is a Jacobi elliptic function of $z=x+iy$; to get $z$, you require the corresponding inverse Jacobi elliptic function. By analogy with trig functions, these go by $\mathrm{arccn}$, $\mathrm{arcsn}$, etc. For your case, we have
$$
z = \mathrm{arccn}\left(\tan\left(\frac{p}{2}\right)e^{i\theta},\frac{1}{2}\right)
$$

The inverse Jacobi elliptic function $\mathrm{arccn}$ has an [expression](http://dlmf.nist.gov/22.15) in terms of an elliptic integral. In general, it is given by

$$
\mathrm{arccn}\left(a,k\right) = \int_{a}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-t^2)(k'^2+k^2t^2)}} dt,
$$

where $k' = \sqrt{1-k^2}$ (see [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/22.2)). In your case, $k=1/2$ and so $k'=\sqrt{3}/2$, and $a=\tan\left(\frac{p}{2}\right)e^{i\theta}$. So,

$$
z = \int_{\tan\left(\frac{p}{2}\right)e^{i\theta}}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-t^2)\left(\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{4}t^2\right)}} dt
$$

So, for a given $p$ and $\theta$, you have to crunch that integral numerically. Or, you maybe be able to find a good elliptical integral package that does this for you, for complex arguments. The real part would be your $x$, and the imaginary part your $y$. As a final note, I'm not sure about the value $k=1/2$ from the Wikipedia article; [this](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1011/1011.3189.pdf) article seems to use the value of $k=k'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: Awesome answer! And thanks for the link to that article. I was hoping to avoid integrals so I could run my code as a graphics shader, but there's no reason I couldn't just precompute the projection.

Comment: Indeed I agree that the k value you suggest seems correct, since it results in the singularities being at {-1,1,i,-i} which are the points on the circle (equator of the polar conformal proj, which is the space of the '=' of OP's equation) that map to corners of the square; with k=1/2 you have {+/-1,+/- i*sqrt(3) }. The wikipedia formula appears to have been sourced from the paper you have linked (same description of p and w, rendered confusing in the WP due to removal from context ) and originally had k=sqrt(1/2) but the k was 'corrected' in Aug 2012...

Comment: ... except - the extrema of Im(cm(z,1/2)) along the other diagonal appear to be +/-1 as expected, so, I'm guessing this may be an issue with different conventions about the 2nd parameter of cm..  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%5B++cn%281.85+%2B+x%2AI%2C1%2F2%29%5D+from+-2.1+to+2.1

Comment: @greggo Good sleuthing regarding the WP page; I did not think to look into the history of that page, but it did strike me that the notation was identical between the two sources. I suspect you're right about conventions for the parameters of these functions; there are always slightly different meanings/normalizations/scalings of what are essentially the same special function. If I get time, I'll implement the projection and visually inspect the results; it should be obvious which is the "correct" $k$ value.

Comment: The definite integral you give -- if I write the bottom right factor as (1/2 + 1/2 t^2) -- seems to exactly match the inverse of cn(z, 1/2), as wolfram evaluates it.

Answer (score 3):

I've found this implementation to work, using the scipy package in python. The implementation is actually just the 'peirce_map' function at the bottom; the rest of it is to obtain a cn() function that works on complex numbers.

```
import numpy
from scipy.special import ellipj, ellipk

#
# The scipy implementation of ellipj only works on reals;
# this gives cn(z,k) for complex z. 
# It works with array or scalar input.
#
def cplx_cn( z, k):
    z = numpy.asarray(z)
    if z.dtype != complex:
        return ellipj(z,k)[1]

    # note, 'dn' result of ellipj is buggy, as of Mar 2015
    # see https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3904
    ss,cc = ellipj( z.real, k )[:2]
    dd = numpy.sqrt(1-k*ss**2)   # make our own dn
    s1,c1 = ellipj( z.imag, 1-k )[:2]
    d1 = numpy.sqrt(1-k*s1**2)

    # UPDATE: scipy bug seems to have been fixed mid 2016, so 
    # four lines above could be done as these two, if you have that.
    #   ss,cc,dd = ellipj( z.real, k )
    #   s1,c1,d1 = ellipj( z.imag, 1-k )

    ds1 = dd*s1
    den = (1-ds1**2)
    rx = cc*c1/den
    ry = ss*ds1*d1/den
    return rx - 1j*ry
#
# Kval is the first solution to cn(x,1/2) = 0
# This is K(k) (where 4*K(k) is the period of the function).
Kval = ellipk(0.5) # 1.8540746773013719

#######################################################
# map a complex point in unit square to unit circle
# The following points are the corners of the square (and map to themselves):
#     1    -1     j    -j
#  The origin also maps to itself.
# Points which are in : abs( re(z)) <=1, abs(im(z)) <=1, but outside the square, will map to
# points outside the unit circle, but are still consistent with mapping a full-sphere
# peirce projection to a full-sphere stereographic projection; however that means that
# the corners 1+j, 1-j, -1+j -1-j all map to the 'south pole' at infinity. You will get
# a divide-by-zero, or near to it, at or near those points.
# It works with array or scalar input.
#
def peirce_map( z ):
    return cplx_cn( Kval*(1-z), 0.5 )
```

Comment: Thanks! Got here googling for a complex implementation of the Jacobi elliptic function and this did the trick.